# Embedded Tomcat of Spring boot shuts down immediately after starting

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Not able to understand why it is shutting down immediately. No errors in the logs as well.
The Tomcat logs are as below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Jul 16, 2018 10:29:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jul 16, 2018 10:29:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
Jul 16, 2018 10:29:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Jul 16, 2018 10:29:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: jolokia: No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jul 16, 2018 10:30:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? The appearance of Tomcat 8.5.11 and Log4J in the logs both suggest it’s rather old. Also, the log output isn’t in Boot’s standard format. It looks like your setup is a bit unusual. Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)?